# Is there a way to avoid that the submit binding of knockoutjs sends the form when pressing the enter key?

Tags: knockout.js

According to the documentation (knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html) the submit binding of knockoutjs has the advantage that it captures alternative ways to submit the form, such as pressing the enter key while typing into a text box. 
I have a grid on my form and some users are trying to use the enter key to go from one field to the next. Is there a way to avoid submitting the form when this happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One choice is to add a `keypress` handler on the form as well that absorbs the enter key.  It would look like:

```
<form data-bind="event: { keypress: absorbEnter }, submit: test">
    <div data-bind="absorbEnter: true">
    <input data-bind="value: name">
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </div>
</form>
```

​
js:

```
var viewModel = {
    name: ko.observable("test"),
    absorbEnter: function(data, event) {
       return event.keyCode !== 13;  
    },
    test: function() {
        console.log("submitting", arguments);        
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/FvZXj/2/

Comment: Could even add it to a bindingHandler to take it out of your view model like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/FvZXj/3/

Comment: can KO differentiate between key up and key down?

Comment: @FutuToad - you can bind against keyup or keydown as necessary using the event binding